# Android circular path progressbar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I've checked out the other questions about circular progressbar and still no helpfull answer. Is there any way I can buid this in android? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdx7zvsE4Y4 
Also, I've found this library https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar 
Does anyone know how can I import the library in my project?

Comment: That library [has a sample](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar/tree/master/sample) that should provide all you need for getting started with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've put the sample in my workspace, but the eclipse does not recognize it. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Do you have Eclipse set up to do Gradle builds? If not, you are going to have a hard time getting that library working, as it uses Gradle.

Comment: No, I don't think so, I've got eclipse once with the Android SDK Bundle. But thank you for your answers, I'm going to search about that.

Comment: If you are just starting a new project, you might consider using Android Studio instead of Eclipse, as that provides great built-in support for Gradle.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to give it a try, thank you!